# sshd_selinux_copy_context: getcon failed with No such file or directory (SFTP from Windows to a chrooted account)

Tags: rhel, windows, chroot, sftp

A colleage is attempting to sftp into a RHEL7 server from Windows using an SFTP client and SSH passwordless login.  **The user account is [chrooted](https://serverfault.com/questions/581323/sftp-gives-permission-denied-only-when-chrooted/797967#797967) at the server.**

openssh version `6.6.1` is installed on the RHEL7 server.

After a failed SFTP connection attempt I checked `/var/log/secure` on the server and discovered the following:

```
Sep 12 17:00:22 serverbox sshd[32652]: Accepted publickey for specialuser from 1.1.1.77 port 58776 ssh2: RSA FINGERPRINT
Sep 12 17:00:22 serverbox sshd[32652]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user specialuser by (uid=0)
Sep 12 17:00:22 serverbox sshd[32652]: sshd_selinux_copy_context: getcon failed with No such file or directory [postauth]
Sep 12 17:01:18 serverbox sshd[32652]: Received disconnect from 1.1.1.77: 11: disconnected by user [postauth]
Sep 12 17:01:18 serverbox sshd[32652]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user specialuser
```

*The same error appears when trying connection from Putty SFTP or Filezilla (both configured to use the local private key).*

Here's the getcon line for easier reading:

`sshd_selinux_copy_context: getcon failed with No such file or directory [postauth]`

So the public key is accepted, then Putty (and Filezilla SFTP) drops after it can't find something it is looking for.

**Permissions:**

```
drwxr-xr-x. root root /home/specialuser
drwx------. specialuser sftponly   /home/specialuser/.ssh
drw-------. specialuser sftponly   /home/specialuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**Valid public key on server:**

```
[user@server]# ssh-keygen -l -f authorized_keys
2048 sha1:fi:ng:er:pr:in:tt  rsa-key-20160913 (RSA)
```

For the rest of the chrooted setup, please check [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/581323/sftp-gives-permission-denied-only-when-chrooted/797967#797967) I posted on another question.

**SFTP with chrooted account works fine from Linux clients:**

I created the same user account (`specialuser`) on my local Linux system (Ubuntu), copied the local account's `id_rsa.pub` to the server's `/home/specialuser/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and was able to sftp right in no problem.

**SELinux ruled out**

To assist in troubleshooting, I temporarily disabled SELinux but continue seeing the same error 'getcon failed...' with attempts from Windows/Putty.

**Same problem with PasswordAuthentication enabled**

I also temporarily enabled PasswordAuthentication for `specialuser`, and this still results in Putty exiting and the above 'getcon failed' error appearing in the server's `/var/log/secure` file.

Log data from that attempt (verbose):

```
Sep 14 10:34:32 serverbox sshd[41228]: Accepted password for specialuser from 1.1.1.77 port 61135 ssh2
Sep 14 10:34:32 serverbox sshd[41228]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user specialuser by (uid=0)
Sep 14 10:34:32 serverbox sshd[41228]: User child is on pid 41283
Sep 14 10:34:32 serverbox sshd[41228]: Changed root directory to "/home/specialuser" [postauth]
Sep 14 10:34:32 serverbox sshd[41228]: sshd_selinux_copy_context: getcon failed with No such file or directory [postauth]
Sep 14 10:34:32 serverbox sshd[41228]: Starting session: forced-command (config) 'internal-sftp' for specialuser from 1.1.1.77 port 61135 [postauth]
Sep 14 10:34:32 serverbox sshd[41228]: Connection closed by 1.1.1.77 [postauth]
Sep 14 10:34:32 serverbox sshd[41228]: Transferred: sent 1976, received 1728 bytes [postauth]
Sep 14 10:34:32 serverbox sshd[41228]: Closing connection to 1.1.1.77 port 61135 [postauth]
Sep 14 10:34:32 serverbox sshd[41228]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user specialuser
```

**EDIT**

I created a separate, non-chrooted, user on the server.  I'm able to use `Putty` and `Putty SFTP` to `SSH/SFTP` to the server with the public/private key.

The problem is getting to the [chrooted home folder](https://serverfault.com/questions/581323/sftp-gives-permission-denied-only-when-chrooted/797967#797967).

**APPENDIX 1: log data with `LogLevel DEBUG3`**

https://justpaste.it/ycdi
*(output exceeds max allowed characters for this question)*

**sshd_config**

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp #added
Match group sftponly
        PasswordAuthentication yes
        ChrootDirectory %h
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Comment: How do you do the Chroot?

Comment: Exactly like this: http://serverfault.com/questions/581323/sftp-gives-permission-denied-only-when-chrooted/797967#797967

Comment: What openssh version are you using? That is not error, but just a message not causing the disconnect. Can you retry with `LogLoevel DEBUG3` in `sshd_config` to see what is going on there and when the disconnect appears?

Comment: `openssh 6.6.1`.  Will set DEBUG3 and comment back when output is added to the question.

Comment: Here is DEBUG3:  https://justpaste.it/ycdi